# How to pass array contoller to blade view?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a product label. While I create an array and pass it to the blade it's not working.

-> Controller

```
        $item_name = $request->input('item_name');
        $label_quantity = $request->input('label_quantity');
        foreach ($item_name as $key => $name) {
            $product = Product::find($item_name[$key]);
            $barcode = Stock::where('product_id', '=', $item_name[$key])->get();
            $data = [
                'name' => $product->name,
                'price' => $product->sale_price,
                'barcode' => $barcode[0]['barcode'],
                'quantity' => $label_quantity[$key],
            ];
            return back()->with(compact('data'));
        }
```

-> Blade File

```
@php
if (isset($data)) {
   print_r(json_encode($data));
} else {
   echo 'No Data Available';
}
@endphp
```

Comment: you are not passing data to a view you are returning a redirect and flashing data to the session ... you would have to pass this data (from the session) to the view that you are rendering

Comment: First of all, move return line out of the foreach loop. Second, return this: view('view.folder.and.name', compact('data'))

Answer (score 0):

Please specify, what is inside the $item_name variable. Does it contain multiple products data?

If it contains only 1 product data then you change your code like this:

```
$item_name = $request->input('item_name');
$label_quantity = $request->input('label_quantity');

$product = Product::find($item_name[0]);
$barcode = Stock::where('product_id', '=', $item_name[0])->get();
$data = [
    'name' => $product->name,
    'price' => $product->sale_price,
    'barcode' => $barcode[0]['barcode'],
    'quantity' => $label_quantity[0],
];

return redirect('/abc', compact('data'));
```

Here you are redirecting to '/abc' route with $data array. You can also render a view and pass data to it like this:

```
return view('home', compact('data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('your view',  ['data' => $data]);
```

if you want to pass many use compact built in function

```
return view('view name', compact(['data', 'data2', 'data3']));
```

Answer (score 0):

-> Controller

```
$item_name = $request->input('item_name');
    $label_quantity = $request->input('label_quantity');
    foreach ($item_name as $key => $name) {
        $product = Product::find($item_name[$key]);
        $barcode = Stock::where('product_id', '=', $item_name[$key])->get();
        $data = [
            'name' => $product->name,
            'price' => $product->sale_price,
            'barcode' => $barcode[0]['barcode'],
            'quantity' => $label_quantity[$key],
        ];
        return back()->with(array('data'=>$data));
    }
```

-> Blade File

```
@if (session('data'))
    @php
       print_r(json_encode(session('data')));
    @endphp
@endif
```